# Convert boolean index to start/end pairs for runs

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a numpy function that will convert something like:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

to an array of start/end pairs for the contiguous ranges, as:

```
[[1, 2],
 [3, 6],
 [7, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the same principle as in @Serdalis answer, but relying solely on numpy:

```
def start_end(arr):
    idx = np.nonzero(np.diff(arr))[0] + 1
    if arr[0]:
        idx = np.concatenate((np.array([0], dtype=np.intp), idx))
    if arr[-1]:
        idx = np.concatenate((idx, np.array([len(arr)],
                                            dtype=np.intp),))
    return idx.reshape(-1, 2)

>>> start_end([1,1,1,0,0,1,0])
array([[0, 3],
       [5, 6]], dtype=int64)
>>> start_end([0,1,1,1,0,0,1])
array([[1, 4],
       [6, 7]], dtype=int64)
>>> start_end([0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0])
array([[1, 4],
       [6, 7]], dtype=int64)
>>> start_end([1,1,1,0,0,1])
array([[0, 3],
       [5, 6]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I don't have numpy installed but this logic should do it for you.

```
import itertools
x = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]

# get the indices where 1->0 and 0->1
diff = np.diff(x) 
diff_index = diff.nonzero(x)

# pair up the ranges using itertools
def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)

ranges = pairwise(x)
```

Documentation:

[numpy diff](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)
[numpy nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html)
[itertools grouper](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

Comment: Hm, this is very close to working. Diff definitely seems like the way to do it. Can't have a list comprehension, though.

Comment: There you go, no list comprehension, it does return an izip object though.

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_starts_ends(x):
    temp = [0]
    temp.extend(x)
    temp.append(0)
    diffs = np.diff(temp)
    ends = np.where(diffs == -1)[0]
    starts = np.where(diffs == 1)[0]
    return np.vstack((starts, ends)).T
```

Result:

```
>>> find_starts_ends(a)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 6],
       [7, 9]])
>>> find_starts_ends([1,1,0,0,1,1])
array([[0, 2],
       [4, 6]])
```

Comment: Should say `temp = np.concatenate([[0], x, [0]])`, but otherwise almost exactly what I wound up with.